# Tip for a good Database Converter Tool

Tags: database, convert, conversion

I need often to convert a database from a database server to another, for example convert a database in MSSQL to a PostgreSQL or convert a MySQL to PostgreSQL, but also convertion between MySQL and Firebird.

Is there a good tool that allow to convert a database from/to different kind of database server ?

Comment: you've done it again stackoverflow, you're closed a perfectly good question.  ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some interesting converter, therefore i answer myself, maybe this tool could be useful to someone else  :

- ESF Database Migration Toolkit ( http://www.easyfrom.net/ ): This toolkit dramatically cuts the effort, cost, and risk of migrating to/from any of the following database/file systems: Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, IBM DB2, IBM Informix, InterSystems Caché, Teradata, Visual Foxpro, SQLite, FireBird, InterBase, Microsoft Access, Microsoft Excel, Paradox, Lotus, dBase, CSV/Text and transfer any ODBC DSN data source to them.
- [Database Converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbcvt/) : A generic metadata, data, and progam migration tool for various databases.Create, review, and modify migration defition with/without database connectivity.Execute database migration or generate relevant SQL and data files as per user choice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good page on [the postgresql wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL) regarding the conversion **to postgresql**.